# How can I make a temp table of specific datetime data within a range?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am trying to create a temp table (id int, start datetime, end datetime) of a schedule during a range of time. So, it would be populated with specific types of times within a range-- i.e. between 9-1-2019 and 9-13-2019, all Mondays and Tuesdays, start time is 10 am and end time is 60 minutes later.

So, using those examples, I would get

```
1/9-2-2019 10 am/9-2-2019 11am
2/9-3-2019 10 am/9-3-2019 11am
3/9-9-2019 10 am/9-9-2019 11am
4/9-10-2019 10 am/9-10-2019 11am
```

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method uses a recursive CTE.  For instance, for your example:

```
with cte as (
      select convert(datetime, '2019-09-01') as dte
      union all
      select dateadd(day, 1, dte)
      from cte
      where dte < '2019-09-13'
     )
select dateadd(hour, 10, dte),
       dateadd(hour, 11, dte)
from cte
where datename(weekday, dte) in ('Monday', 'Tuesday');
```

If the CTE generates over 100 rows, then you need to add `option (maxrecursion 0)` to the query.

Comment: Thanks. To populate a temp table-- I think I should do this: `create table 
 #schedule_times
 (id int identity(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
 start_datetime datetime, 
 end_datetime datetime)
with cte as 
  (
    select convert(datetime, '2019-09-01') as dte
    union all
    select dateadd(day, 1, dte)
    from cte
    where dte < '2019-09-13'
  )
insert into 
 #schedule_times (start_datetime, end_datetime)
 select
  dateadd(hour, 10, dte),
  dateadd(hour, 11, dte)
 from 
  cte
 where 
  datename(weekday, dte) in ('Monday', 'Tuesday')
drop table 
 #schedule_times `

Comment: @TODBA . . . Or you can just use `select . . . into #schedule_times`.  That creates the table directly from the query

Answer (score 0):

Just another way to do this

```
WITH C AS
(
  SELECT DATEADD(Hour, 10, DATEADD(Day, V-1, '2019-09-01')) StartDate,
         DATEADD(Hour, 11, DATEADD(Day, V-1, '2019-09-01')) EndDate
  FROM
  (
    VALUES (1),
           (2),
           (3),
           (4),
           (5),
           (6),
           (7),
           (8),
           (9),
           (10),
           (11),
           (12),
           (13)
  ) T(V)
)
SELECT *
FROM C
WHERE DATENAME(WeekDay, StartDate) IN ('Monday', 'Tuesday');
```

And if you want to create the temp table directly use

```
SELECT IDENTITY(INT, 1, 1) ID,
       StartDate,
       EndDate
INTO #schedule_times
FROM C
WHERE DATENAME(WeekDay, StartDate) IN ('Monday', 'Tuesday');
```

Comment: Thank you both-- I combined the two ideas and put it into my proc-- works great now.